# You must have either have gettext support in your C library

Tags: integration, gettext, glib, openwrt

I have this error

checking libintl.h presence... no
checking for libintl.h... no
configure: error:
* You must have either have gettext support in your C library, or use the
* GNU gettext library. (​http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/gettext.html

I wonder why this  problem although  I have installed "gettext" lib?

Comment: Uh again, show us code.

Comment: PKG_NAME:=glib2
PKG_VERSION:=2.22.2
PKG_RELEASE:=1
--
PKG_NAME:=gettext-full
PKG_VERSION:=0.18.1.1
PKG_RELEASE:=1

Comment: i have no code ,it's integration problem

Comment: solved : just modify Makefile : remove "-full"

Answer (score 0):

solved : just modify Makefile : remove "-full"